# SVN and syntax highlighting on Android

Tags: android

Anyone know of a Subversion client for Android OS? Same goes for a syntax highlighting text editor on there.

Comment: You want a svn client that runs on the android OS?  Really?  Oh, how about HTTP?

Comment: To be productive and get some small fixes done while away from main work machine.

I plan on using this like the mini computer it is.

Comment: I would think it'd be more productive to setup SSH on your main work machine and install ConnectBot (a decent, free Android SSH client).

Comment: Hmm, I have that app already, so I can do some editing on one of my servers using nano I guess.

I was just hoping for something with a more standard gui and syntax highlighting on the droid

Comment: SVNkit is a pure java svn library. It may work on android.

Answer (score 6):

I have written a SVN Client for android.  It is called Open Android SVN (OASVN)

Here is a link to it on the android play market : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.valleytg.oasvn.android

Can do checkout, update, commit, cleanup, revert, export, and much more in the works.

Works with http, https, svn protocols and svn+ssh is experimental.

I will be adding merging and other features soon.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know anything about its quality, but Subdroid is available in the Android market with both [free](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.feldschmid.subdroid) and [inexpensive](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.feldschmid.subdroid_donate) (~1 euro) versions.

Comment: Subdroid does the job but its not exactly a pleasure to work iwth

Comment: It's view only though, so this just allows for review of code, not checking out and commiting from what I can tell.

Comment: @JoshuaFricke Oh, I didn't notice that. That's disappointing.

Answer (score 2):

I was just thinking today that I'd like a text editor and an SVN client for Android!  I couldn't find the latter, but I do know that http://svnkit.com/ would probably be a pretty good place to start.

Comment: Yeah the svkkit codebase does look promising, just not something I can manage porting at this time.

Comment: If you were to program an app yourself, and didn't want to reimplement the svn back-end code, SVNKit would definitely be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

There is an app called [Touchqode](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.touchqode.editor) which has syntax highlighting and ftp download. It comes with its own "programing optimized" keyboard. It seems pretty good for a beginning of one of the first android IDEs. I guess you can get some compilers for it too.

What I've done a few times is use a SSH client to log into my web server (but it could be your home or work machine), use SVN on there to check out the code, then use Touchqode's FTP function to work on the code from my web server. Not as elegant or convenient as using a real svn client right on Android, but it gets the job done.

From the author:

> Make use of time while commuting or waiting. View and edit source code anywhere.
>   View and edit source code on Android phone. Touchqode is a true mobile code editor that comes with syntax highlighting, autocomplete and other features found in a desktop IDE. We support Java, HTML, JavaScript, Python, C++, C#, Ruby and PHP. Now with integrated FTP and SFTP client.

Answer (score 2):

I just started testing [IDEdroid](http://www.idedroid.com/) and [TextWarrior](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.myopicmobile.textwarrior.android) recently.  My mini review so far for both below:

IDEdroid 
Decent interface and Syntax highlighting, allows you to test code on the ideone.com web site.

TextWarrior
Pretty nice interface, Syntax highlighting for C, C++ and Java only though.

Answer (score 1):

The only text editor I have found that has any kind of syntax highlighting is SilverEdit.  It only does html, css and xml though, and seems generally buggy.

Answer (score 0):

It's an odd request. Going to say it doesn't exist. You might be able to port Eclipse's native-java based SVN client but it would be a hack.

If the SVN server is hosted via HTTP, you could write some Delta-V\WebDav calls to access it without a lot of work.

Comment: I don't think porting something from Eclipse would be very practical, since the SWT/JFace UI frameworks are totally different from Android UI code.  On the other hand, basing an app on the pure Java SVNKit library (as mentioned in another answer) seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

if you root your  phone and install debian on it 
http://www.androidfanatic.com/community-forums.html?func=view&catid=9&id=2248

then you can easily install the debian client

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Android CodePad](http://code.google.com/p/android-codepad/) which has syntax highlighting to browse code. I find writing code on the android phone is too cumbersome in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

AIDE is a new full Android IDE for developing Android apps. It doesn't have SVN support but it can edit, compile, and run Android applications directly on the device. This in combination with an SVN app would be extremely powerful.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui

Comment: This question is about programming on an android device, not for one.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't specify what you were developing for. AIDE is for developing Android apps on an Android device. It does have syntax highlighting and refactoring and whatnot, so it meets your only given requirement of "syntax highlighting text editor."

Comment: I see, so this app could be helpful for some, just not general programming of any language, which was more of what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, just trying to help.